# connect to impala error Connection refused?

Tags: java, sql, hive, impala, bigdata

I am trying to connect from Java program to impala using the below driver

```
com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver
```

but i am getting a sql exception, bellow stack-trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500310) Invalid operation: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect;
at com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(HiveServer2ClientFactory.java:224)
at com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(HiveServer2ClientFactory.java:52)
at com.cloudera.impala.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(HiveJDBCConnection.java:597)
at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(BaseConnectionFactory.java:219)
at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:216)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.gcs.virdict.InsertImpala.generateValue(InsertImpala.java:86)
Caused by: com.cloudera.impala.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500310) Invalid operation: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect;
```

I am also attaching the code below for reference

```
private void connectionImpala() {
  try {  
    Class.forName(IMPALA_DRIVER_NAME);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }
  Connection con = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:impala://IP:21050/default;user=abcde;password=abcde");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    // ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement)
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: What's the content of your sqlStatement variable ?